Div element not going where it should in a navigation bar
I'm new to web developing and I'm trying to make a navigation bar for a small project of mine, but the items don't align properly. Can someone help me? Here is what I get: 
I'm trying to get the search icon to go the upper right corner of the screen. Here are the html and css:


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.amatic-sc-regular {
  font-family: "Amatic SC", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

.amatic-sc-bold {
  font-family: "Amatic SC", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.ul {
  font-family: "Amatic SC";
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.imghref {
  display: block;
  height: 70px;
}

.linkclass {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.linkclass:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.linkclass:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.linkclass:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.linkclass:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu_l {
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-left: 2%;
  padding: 0;
  height: fit-content;
}

.menu_r {
  margin-right: 2%;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbarlogo {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  transform: translateX(+6%);
  transform: translateX(+400%);
}

.logoimg_w {
  width: 170px;
}

.search {
  width: 35px;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="menu" class="navbar">
  <div id="menu_l" class="menu_l">

    <ul id="ul" class="ul">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="linkclass">За нас</a>
        <a href="#" class="linkclass">Ново</a>
        <a href="#" class="linkclass">Тениски</a>
        <a href="#" class="linkclass">Панталони</a>
        <a href="#" class="linkclass">Сиучъри</a>
        <a href="#" class="linkclass">Чорапи</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div id="img" class="navbarlogo">
    <a href="#" id="imghref" class="imghref">
      <img src="rsz_1logo_white.png" class="logoimg_w">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="menu_r" class="menu_r">
    <div class="iconr">
      <a href="#" class="iconhref">
        <img src="search1.png" class="search">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>

</footer>



I have tried messing with the position of the elements, but nothing works. Every time the div just goes to the center, even if I do "align-self: flex-end;". Can someone help me?

To align the search icon to the upper right corner, you need to adjust the layout and positioning of the elements in your navigation bar. Here's an updated version of your HTML and CSS:


body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.amatic-sc-regular {
    font-family: "Amatic SC", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

.amatic-sc-bold {
    font-family: "Amatic SC", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.ul {
    font-family: "Amatic SC";
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.imghref {
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
}

.linkclass {
    color: white;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.linkclass:link,
.linkclass:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.linkclass:hover,
.linkclass:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu_l {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.menu_r {
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.navbar {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbarlogo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.logoimg_w {
    width: 170px;
}

.search {
    width: 35px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu" class="navbar">
        <div id="menu_l" class="menu_l">
            <ul id="ul" class="ul">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="linkclass">За нас</a>
                    <a href="#" class="linkclass">Ново</a>
                    <a href="#" class="linkclass">Тениски</a>
                    <a href="#" class="linkclass">Панталони</a>
                    <a href="#" class="linkclass">Сиучъри</a>
                    <a href="#" class="linkclass">Чорапи</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="img" class="navbarlogo">
            <a href="#" id="imghref" class="imghref">
                <img src="rsz_1logo_white.png" class="logoimg_w">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div id="menu_r" class="menu_r">
            <div class="iconr">
                <a href="#" class="iconhref">
                    <img src="search1.png" class="search">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
</html>



